# How to connect separate docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have built three docker images of node, elastic search, and mongo. Then pushed those to docker hub. after pulling those images, I am running them using the command docker run. They are running successfully. But the node app is not being able to connect to mongo or elastic. I have tried creating a network and adding the containers to it, but it doesn't help. Can someone help regarding the issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, as in where are you running these containers. Have a look at my answer where I have given you relevant pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where the individual containers are running. If they are running on the same host, you can connect them to the same bridge network.
Refer here: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

If they are running on different host, you would have to use host networking and expose the relevant ports. Refer here: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Answer (score 0):

when working with multiple containers it's better to use [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).
you can create a docker-compose.yml file defining services(your containers) there.

Here is an example docker-compose.yml for node,mongo and elasticsearch

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
backend:
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: always
    build: node
    ports:
    - "3010:3010"

    volumes:
    - .:/app
    - ./error.log:/usr/src/app/error.log
    links:
    - mongo
    - elasticsearch
mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
    - ./data:/data/db
elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.0
    environment:
    - node.name=es01
    - discovery.type=single-node
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    volumes:
    -  esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
    - "9200:9200"    
volumes:
esdata:
    driver: local
```

Your question is not clear so I cant answer more than that